# How to build a decentralized bridge between two blockchains?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, oracles, chainlink

I am trying to build my own custom bridge between Ethereum and Binance Smart Chain so that people can transfer tokens and possibly some other assets from one chain to another and vice versa. For this purpose I will need three things:

- smart contract in Ethereum blockchain
- smart contract in BSC blockchain
- some kind of oracle to maintain the communication between contracts in different chains

My question is: how to create a **decentralized** oracle, that can subscribe to events from one chain and cast them to contract in another chain?

I think I can use Chainlink to achieve this, but for now the only way I see is following:

1. User executes transaction on contract in Ethereum blockchain.
2. Smart contract emits event in Ethereum blockchain.
3. My own custom oracle detects that event was emitted and executes transaction to BSC chain in order to notify the BSC contract about the event.
4. BSC smart contract verifies that this particular event exists in Ethereum blockchain. For this purpose smart contract executes API request to some known provider (like Etherscan) using Chainlink mechanisms.

The thing is: I don't want to rely on any API-s in my bridge (so no Etherscan and alike). I want to rely only on blockchain events and decentralized oracles that can detect and propagate those events. Are there any existing mechanisms I can use for this matter?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds similar to what [DeBridge Finance](https://debridge.finance/) did in the last Chainlink Hackathon. Suggest having a read of their [docs](https://docs.debridge.finance/the-core-protocol/protocol-overview), and checking out their [code](https://github.com/debridge-finance/) for an idea of how they architected a decentralized bridge between multiple chains

Comment: As far as I can tell in DeBridge approach I still need to create my own centralized API (or use existing one) for verifying blockchain events (that happened in another blockchain). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: By default, a CL node looks at a single particular network (eg ETH Mainnet, Ropsten etc). What you're describing is for a CL node to look for events on a particular network (eg ETH), but then have a job that submits a tx to another network. This is not currently possible, and you would need to use an API like DeBridge did for now.

In the future, perhaps the core CL node will be modified to handle this kind of scenario, but for now it's not possible with the current version of it

Comment: Could you confirm you haven't heard so far about fully decentralised solution for this?