# How can we connect two different private blockchains to each other in Geth?

Tags: private-blockchain, cross-chain, interoperability

I have two blockchains that are working separately. I'm trying to connect them. This connection can help me to make communication between one node in blockchain 1 and another node in blockchain 2. Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What data will blockchains have to exchange?

Comment: Perhaps do you want a bridge https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99798/how-to-build-a-decentralized-bridge-between-two-blockchains?

Comment: The private blockchains are working separately on my computer. They should speak together to convey information about their status and after the decision money or tokens.

Comment: The important thing that I need is to connect two private blockchains. I think these bridges are connecting two public blockchains.

Comment: My private blockchains and my nodes have been made on Geth.